# Is there a way to get long, lat info without using google in R?

Tags: r, geolocation, mapping, latitude-longitude

I have an csv file with information of cities in R. Now I need, instead of the cities, their long and lat information. Later on I want to plot these information to a map.

I tried multiple codes, but they all worked with google, which isn't working.

Does anyone of you know a way how to get long, lat information without using google API?

Comment: Is it "google" or "web api" that you're trying to avoid? I think you need to be much clearer with your question here, as asking us to recommend off-site resources is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you google "long lat major cities csv" any of the first few hits will get you something you could probably use. You can get a csv you can download and load into R with read.csv.

Comment: Have a look at osm and osrm.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you probably want to check the `geocode_OSM` function in the `tmaptools` package. For example:

```r
# packages
library(tmaptools)

# simple example
geocode_OSM("Milan, Italy")
#> $query
#> [1] "Milan, Italy"
#> 
#> $coords
#>       x       y 
#>  9.1905 45.4668 
#> 
#> $bbox
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#>  9.040887 45.386738  9.278110 45.535848
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

That function uses OpenStreetMap Nominatim and you should read the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). You should also read the help page of the function (just type `?tmaptools::geocode_OSM`) and check the examples.